# Get count and if less than X get name of last row entered

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do two things at once in the same select statement in mysql. My users can upload images.  The image file name is saved in a table. The users can only upload 10 images.  If the user loads less than 10 and then comes back later to upload some more I need to know how many have already been uploaded and what the last file name is (I rename the files on upload adding a number to each for this very reason). I have been fiddling with this:

```
    SELECT COUNT(vendimagepath) AS id , vendimagepath   
   FROM vendimages  WHERE   vendregid = '$vendredig' 
   ORDER BY vendimagepath  DESC
```

It gives me the number of files already uploaded which is half the battle but then gives seems to be a random file name from that users uploads.  I might be barking up the wrong tree and may need to break it into two queries but was trying not to do that is such quick succession. I think Im close to getting it but just not close enough.

Comment: Do you have a schema (DDL) for the table you are using?  This would help.

Comment: if your count column contains numbers/integers but using varchar as the type, then that will explain the random filename. The question is unclear and as already asked, provide the db schema for this. However, the title you say "if less than X"; what do you mean exactly? Usually you would iterate over rows and check like `if($row['x'] >= 10)`, so you really need to clarify your question. Oh, and if you know how to ping someone with the @ symbol; do. I for one won't stay here for hours on end.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date column on this table (e.g. `created`) you could order DESC by that column and then for the first record use the LIMIT clause.

```
SELECT  b.nbr_of_images,
        a.vendimagepath,
        a.created   
FROM vendimages a,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) as nbr_of_images,
               vendregid
        FROM vendimages
        WHERE vendregid = '$vendredig'
        GROUP BY vendregid) b 
WHERE a.vendregid = b.vendregid
AND a.vendregid = '$vendredig'
ORDER BY a.created DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Results:

```
NBR_OF_IMAGES   VENDIMAGEPATH   CREATED
3               /usr/png2       8/4/2016 18:08:50
```